# Templated Sum(Args...) variadic function doesn't compile

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I used static struct member trick to enforce 2nd pass compilation and still get an error:

```
struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    static T Sum(T t) {
        return t;
    }

    template <typename T, typename ... Rest>
    static auto Sum(T t, Rest... rest) -> decltype(t + Sum(rest...) )
    {
        return t + Sum(rest...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto x = S::Sum(1,2,3,4,5);
}
```

main.cpp:17:14: No matching function for call to 'Sum'

Comment: [This code runs fine on ideone](http://ideone.com/8IUflw), producing `x` of 15.

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: @UKMonkey Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even using `clang 4.0` the compilation fails.

I managed to compile it using `decltype(auto)` (solely `auto` will work too) instead of the explicit tail return type.

```
struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    static T Sum(T t) {
        return t;
    }

    template <typename T, typename ... Rest>
    static decltype(auto) Sum(T t, Rest... rest) 
    {
        return t + Sum(rest...);
    }
};
```

---

I think that the compiler is not able to the deduce the type cause the deduction depends only by a recursive return statement.

[More info here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3386.html)

Comment: is there any reason to use `decltype(auto)` deduction (and not `auto`)?

Comment: @Mike, I don't think it would make any difference in this specific case.

Comment: any reason why not just return type T - we know it's safe because of T sum(T) ?

Comment: @UKMonkey it's not safe. Try to call it using `auto x = S::Sum(1,2.5,3.0);` and see what happens. you get `6` as a result while you should get `6.5`. It happens because the first parameter is `int` and so the is the return type to the call that return to `main` the final result. What you want as return type is the type of the result of the whole sum.